# CSS Styling - Aside behavior not working?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div>
 <article>
     <aside>
         Text inside Aside
         <p>
             Text inside P inside Aside
         </p>
         <h4>Header inside Aside</h4>
         <section>
            <h4>Header inside Section inside Aside</h4>
         </section>
     </aside>
 </article>
```

I have the following CSS that goes with it:

```
    h4 {
        color: blue;
    }
    article{
        color: black;
    }
    aside{
        color: purple;
    }
    aside p{
        color: gray;
    }
    aside h4{
        font-style: italic !important;
        color: yellow;
    }
    article h4{
        color: brown;
    } 
    section h4{
        color: orange;
    }
```

Why is it that the "Header inside Aside" shows up as purple instead of yellow? All the other elements seem to show the expected color. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Brown, and its because you set the `article h4` after `aside h4`... just switch the order to make it yellow.

```css
h4 {
        color: blue;
    }
    article{
        color: black;
    }
    article h4{
        color: brown;
    }
    aside{
        color: purple;
    }
    aside p{
        color: gray;
    }
    aside h4{
        font-style: italic !important;
        color: yellow;
    }
    section h4{
        color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div>
 <article>
     <aside>
         Text inside Aside
         <p>
             Text inside P inside Aside
         </p>
         <h4>Header inside Aside</h4>
         <section>
            <h4>Header inside Section inside Aside</h4>
         </section>
     </aside>
 </article>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning behind this is the way CSS renders your page.

Put it simply, it looks at it **top down**. The ones in the end override.